# React navigation set initial route to another stack screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

I have a react native app using react navigation. My app has 3 different stacks = `{ ROOT, AUTH, USER }`.

Stacks `ROOT` & `AUTH` are managed by authentication flow, if there's a token I switch to `ROOT` otherwise `AUTH`. That works fine. In my `USER` stack, is where I place "universal" screens (screens that can be accessed either from root or auth stack). Let's consider one of my `USER` stack screen is `ValidateUserAccount` (which is accessed through a link from the email). The problem comes when for example I open my app and I'm in the `LoginScreen`, in the `AUTH` stack. On iOS, the go back has the previous screen title. Since the previous screen it's in another stack , it shows `"< auth"`, instead of `"< login"`. Same happens with the `ROOT`. If I'm at `HomeScreen`, in the `ROOT` stack and I open the `ValidateUserAccount`, the go back button is `"< root"`.

```
<MainStack.Navigator
  screenOptions={{
    headerShown: false
  }}>
  {accessToken ? (
    <MainStack.Screen
      name="root"
      component={BottomTabNavigator}
    />
  ) : (
    <MainStack.Screen
      name="auth"
      component={AuthenticationStack}
    />
  )}
  <MainStack.Screen
    name="user"
    component={UserStack}></RootStack.Screen>
</MainStack.Navigator>
```

How can I manage to display the go back with the previous screen title instead of previous stack title, eventhough it's in another stack?

Is it possible? or the only solution is to hide the go back title?